# Select an item from HTML dropdown menu in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I download a webpage to WebView and try to select an item from a HTML drop-down menu () by JavaScript. Could anyone show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```